# Is it possible to retranslate (tr) QString const?

Tags: c++, qt, constants, qstring, language-translation

I have this challenge. I am trying to avoid `#define NEW_LABEL "---New label---"`.

I would like to do it in the proper way via `define class constant`.

*myclass.h*

```
class MyClass:public QDialog{ 
private:
Ui::MyClassWidget* ui;
const QString NEW_LABEL_TEXT;
}
```

*myclass.cpp*

```
//const init

MyClass::MyClass():ui(new Ui::MyClassWidget),NEW_LABEL_TEXT(tr("---New label---")){
some stuff..
}
```

My question is:

Is it a right way, when I want to retranslate to other language? Can the QString const be dynamically retranslated?

ATC

Thank you for answers and tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `QWidget` derived class, such as `QDialog`, you can listen for translation language change.

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog {
protected:
  virtual void changedEvent(QEvent * event) override {
         if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
             /* call tr again here */
             /* for ui object just call retranslateUi to automatically update translations */
             ui->retranslateUi(this);
          }

          QDialog::changedEvent(e);
   }
};
```

So you can retranslate a string at runtime everytime language change, but you cannot store the result in a `const QString`, just store the result in a static QString if you want to have a class scope for this translation.

Comment: Thanks. So I should make `static QString NEW_LABEL_TEXT` instead of `QString const`?

Comment: Making a const QString will let you unable to modify it after its initialization. Making it static is a possibility, but reming that the changedEvent will be call on every Dialog instances you have when the language changes.

Comment: I think, that it solves the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the string constant untranslated.  But mark it with `QT_TR_NOOP()` so that Linguist can see it, and store it as a plain `char const*`.

Then when you come to actually use it, translate it as usual, with `QApplication::translate`, or with `tr()` of your class:

```
// MyClass: Hello! -> Dobrý deň
static const uchar translations[] = {
  60, 184, 100,  24, 202, 239, 156, 149, 205,  33,  28, 191,  96, 161, 189, 221,
  66,   0,   0,   0,   8,   4, 236,  51,  17,   0,   0,   0,   0, 105,   0,   0,
   0,  52,   3,   0,   0,   0,  18,   0,  68,   0, 111,   0,  98,   0, 114,   0,
 253,   0,  32,   0, 100,   0, 101,   1,  72,   8,   0,   0,   0,   0,   6,   0,
   0,   0,   6,  72, 101, 108, 108, 111,  33,   7,   0,   0,   0,   7,  77, 121,
  67, 108,  97, 115, 115,   1,  47,   0,   0,   1,  58,   0, 151,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   7,  77, 121,
  67, 108,  97, 115, 115, 136,   0,   0,   0,   6,   1,   1, 255,   4,   2,   4,
};
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static const char *const message = QT_TR_NOOP("Hello!");

    QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
    QTranslator translator;
    if (!translator.load(translations, sizeof translations))
        qFatal("Failed to load translations");
    app.installTranslator(&translator);

    qInfo() << app.translate("MyClass", message);
    // or tr(message) in your own MyClass object
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try it. It seems fine.